# I bought Minecraft for the Xbox one but can't get it on the PC

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I bought Minecraft for the Xbox One, which in turn gave me the Windows 10 Edition for free (still on my Xbox.) Now I want to play on PC for a school project in com tech, but it says I have not purchased it. Does that mean I have to buy the game again or is there a way around this?

Answer (score 3):

Minecraft Java edition (for computers) is a completely separate game from whatever you can buy on consoles.

Answer (score 1):

You have to download it off of the windows store application. Make sure you are logged into the same Microsoft account as the one you bought Minecraft for Xbox.

Comment: I went to minecraft on Microsoft store on my pc, but it just said "play free trial"